# HIve subquery in where clause

Tags: hive, hadoop2

i am new to hive please help me, i have a table name prac and i need to
find the products which give more profit(price-cost) than product Mouse. I have tried the below query but it is not working.

```
select product_name,price-cost 
from   prac 
where  price-cost > (select price-cost from prac where product_name='mouse')
```

and my data is

```
id,product_name,product_type,price,cost,date
100,maker,stationary,25,22,2008-01-15
101,mouse,computer,450,350,2009-04-16
102,white  board,stationary,450,375,2010-06-25
103,sony viao,computer,35000,42000,2010-09-21
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer

```
select a.*,a.price-a.cost profit
from prac a 
join (select price-cost p from prac where p_name='Maker') b 
where a.price-a.cost>b.p;
```

Comment: Kindly let me know if there is another way to solve this.